# How to make both host and guest visible on the Internet with QEMU?

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

Here is what I am trying to achieve. Using the bridge helper described here [wiki](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/HelperNetworking) I want to connect both my host and my guest to the Internet.

Here is what I am doing, the commands roughly look like this. I create a bridge

`ip link add br0 type bridge`

then I add my real Ethernet interface to it,

`ip link set enp2s0 master br0` (or sth like this, can't remember the exact command)

then set the Ethernet interface's state up, the same with the bridge, then flush the ip address of the Ethernet interface and assign an ip to the bridge, like this

`dhclient br0`

After this, I am able to ping google.com from host, which means I can resolve DNS and stuff, so I am connected to the Internet.

Next, I run qemu like this

`qemu-system-i386 {the image} -netdev bridge,id=hn0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hn0,id=nic1`

This is the exact command that I am typing now. See I use qemu-system-* syntax, because it seems like it superseded the previous syntax.

After that, my image boots fine, in the logs I can see something about virtio-pci, and that, I suppose, means that the command worked exactly as it was meant to work. And indeed my guest can ping google.com, it is connected to the Internet like it was installed on bare metal (it sees eth0 device, everything seems fine).

Here is my problem and question at the same time.

Right now, the ip addresses of the host and guest are the same. Is it okay? The reason I am asking is that after the guest boots and pings google.com, I can't ping google.com from my host! But if I run

`dhclient br0`

from host, I can then take my Internet access back and ping google.com.

- Do I need to take care of assigning different ip addresses to host and guest? And if so, how do I do it?
- Or maybe the problem is with tap devices? At least till this moment, I though that QEMU should take care of everything with the setup that I described, but maybe I need to tweak some properties of the TAP  device that it created?

Comment: IP addresses must be unique.  If you're getting your IP from your ISP, you'll need to contact them for another one.  Alternately, use a NAT setup.  It's unclear if you're connecting your computer directly to the internet through a modem (not good security), or you're behind a router.

Comment: @essjae How do I tell if I am behind a router? I guess I get my ip address from ISP, this is a regular home setup. The only thing I can tell which may be relevant is that I have also played with ```ip route``` command and checked what routes I had, so maybe that implies no modem? In fact, I am connected with an Ethernet cable (and the NI name is enp2s0, which is for Ethernet devices, I suppose)

Comment: You can check the device you're connected to on a search engine to see if it's a router. "Most" home setups have a router/modem combo.  Otherwise, you can tell by the IP, if you've got a non-routeable IP, 192.168.x.x., 172.16.x.x, or 10.x.x.x then you're behind a router.  If its a weird set of numbers, you're directly connected.